# How to Enable Google Maps Earth View without Plugin

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-earth-plugin

I'm evaluating options for a 3d globe viewer that doesn't require any download/install. As an alternative to [Cesium.js](http://cesiumjs.org/), I'm also taking a look at [Google Maps Js API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

Recently I've noticed that WebGL enabled browsers seem to be able to switch into Earth view in Google Maps - **without the plugin?**

This is not to be confused with the [45° View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#45DegreeImagery), which is [still fairly limited in its coverage.](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?ll=8.787199,-45.827047&t=h&source=embed&dap&ie=UTF8&msa=0&spn=85.447389,153.703486&hl=en&mid=z3LmnfPRZzFk.kmewUZ7S-AVw)

Here's a screenshot of [Sydney in Google Maps](https://www.google.com.au/maps/@-35.3403862,149.1558593,15z) using the Tilt control (seen in bottom right corner, once you select Earth view):

[image]

How can I implement this functionality?
I can't seem to find it documented anywhere, is this not released in the JS API yet?

Even if you try the embed code for this (iframe) the Earth View is replaced by Satellite?

I basically just want the user to be able to control the pitch/heading?

Comment: I think this is using the deprecated Google Earth API: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/camera_control

Comment: @Andy Yes it certainly looks similar; however standard Google Maps is currently providing this functionality without the need for installing the plugin. I'm guessing that given the plugin is deprecated, this functionality may merge into the JS API down the track.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Google has many map engines, and most of them they are getting rid of at the end-of-2015 and early 2016, its a bit complicated following their press and developer releases.

As I understand it, what is available on their own online "maps.google.com" site:

- The online maps site (in late 2014 and beyond) is now driven by their "My Maps" engine which is a rename of the "Maps Engine Lite".  My Maps/Maps Engine Lite offers the new "Earth View" implementation rather than old the "Satellite View".
- Google's old online maps engine (called "Classic Maps") was still available in 2015 and can be force-invoked on Google's online maps site.  It still offers the old "Satellite View" but not the "Earth View".
- This switch-over happened in Sept 2014.
- Their even more powerful "Maps Engine" (which offered excellent image "draping" capabilities) is being terminated by Google now in January 2016.

However, for "Google Maps Javascript API V3":

- it is still driven by the "Classic Maps" engine, which only has access to the "Satellite View" mode.
- We are all hoping that there will be an upcoming Google Maps Javascript API V4 in 2016 that would provide access to the new Maps Engine Lite, and therefore access to the "Earth View" mode.
- Given Google's updated end-of-life notice (now stating "Early 2016" rather then "End of 2015") of the Google Earth Plugin, that lends some credence to the hopes there will be a new 2016 javascript API that gives access to the "Earth View" mode.

For my own purposes, I'm still successfully using (at December 2015) the Google Maps Javascript API to Google Earth plugin adapter code that Google published.

Various supporting articles ( I can only post 2 links at my reputation level):

http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/mapseng_lite.html

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-engine-users/IfqS90d8f0A

Comment: Doesn't *really* solve my problem... but I guess I can't blame you for that ;)