# Google Maps Earth View future

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps Earth View has never provided any solid plugin-free API to work the same native way as we do with Google Maps API.

Now when Google Maps Earth View API is deprecated, we have no any means to interact with the Earth View. Needless to say that world explorations are not convenient using that default scanty set of tools provided by the Earth View. At that, Earth View now is the default physical map browsing map type at maps.google.com.

Does anybody have any information about some future plans of Google to support developers?

Comment: Currently there is a feature request in the public issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7526. No timeline available, though you can star it to show your interest.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, upon the deprecation of [Google Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/faq?hl=en), plugins has been provided such as the Google Earth Browser Plug-in that allows users to navigate and explore geographic data on a 3D globe. The look and feel of the plugin is similar to the Google Earth application, thereby providing a similar user experience. However, there are also differences such as the one discussed in this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/KzPyxvMOlGI).

To be kept updated with the latest product updates or upcoming plans, I would suggest that you follow or subscribe to the following links:

- [Google Earth Blog](http://www.gearthblog.com/)
- [Google Maps API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/)
- [Google Maps Android API - Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases)
- [Google Maps JavaScript API -  Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases)
- [Google Earth releases](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/40901)

Lastly, this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802234/how-to-enable-google-maps-earth-view-without-plugin) might also help.